# IQR and Quartiles are not generated as expected in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am new to R and statistics. Please bear with me in this question.

I want to find the Quartiles and IQR of numbers from 1:8.
I calculated to find that Q2 = (4+5)/2 = 4.5
Q1 = (2+3)/2 = 2.5 and Q3 = (6+7)/2 = 6.5

The IQR = 6.5-2.5 = 4

However R is giving some different values. I am not able to understand where am I wrong.

```
> quantile(1:8)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100%
1.00 2.75 4.50 6.25 8.00

> IQR(1:8)
[1] 3.5
```

It'll be great if someone could point out my mistake.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134229/finding-quartiles-in-r

Comment: @MitchWheat Exactly! Nearly the same thing. But I am unable to figure out how it is calculating the first quartile. Like even if it takes 1,2,3,4,5 the Q1 = 3. How it is computing 2.75?

Comment: The quantile() function has 9(!) different ways to calculate quartiles: https://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e17/help/att-1067/Quartiles_in_R.pdf

Comment: @MitchWheat, pweh! That's kind of tough. Well let me just keep it in mind for the time being. Just one more question - Is the text book wrong in my case as well as in the stats.stackexchange question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your textbook appears to be using a definition of quantile that is different to R's [`quantile()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.4.3/topics/quantile) function default method. [R's quantile() function 9 different ways to calculate quartiles.]

Try

```
> quantile(1:8, type = 5)

  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
 1.0  2.5  4.5  6.5  8.0
```

Whereas, R's default is `type = 7`:

```
> quantile(1:8, type = 7)

  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
1.00 2.75 4.50 6.25 8.00
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. :)